# How to pass query string in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I have following code in vue.js file

```
<p>{{match.tournament_name}}<p>
```

Above code will print tournament name inside p tag.

Now I want to pass `match.tournament_name` as query string for my a tag. But I am not sure how to do string interpolation in Vue.js. I have tried like this

```
<a href="/score_cards/new?tournament_name={{match.tournament_name}}">Upload Score Card</a>
```

But above string interpolation doesn't work. So How can I pass `match.tournament_name` as query string ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you can use v-bind attributes. For example:

```
<a v-bind:href="`/score_cards/new?tournament_name=${match.tournament_name}`">Upload Score Card</a>
```

Also you can use reduction `:href` instead of `v-bind:href`